# Liquibase bundled action instead of sql check constraint for enum types

Tags: liquibase

Given I have following changeset which want to enforce only listed values are allowed:

```
<changeSet author="Liquibase Master" id="CH_ACCOUNT_STATUS">
    <sql>alter table ACCOUNT add constraint CH_ACCOUNT_STATUS
        check (STATUS in ('draft','active','cancelled'));
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Such changeset is especially useful when I have enumeration in the code:

```
public enum AccountStatus {
    draft
    active,
    cancelled
}
```

Is there any bundled liquibase action which would replace sql specific definition above?

Comment: "*which would replace sql specific definition*" - replace with what?

Comment: I can't find add check constraint which would be similar to http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_not_null_constraint.html

Comment: it might be it does not exist and it could be new feature request for liquibase devs

Comment: Liquibase does not support a generic check constraint tag (maybe because the devs all use MySQL) The commercial version ("Datical") does support check constraint though. For Oracle there is an extension which supports them: https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Oracle+Extensions

Comment: interesting, thanks for this info